# Is it possible to mantain the sequence of operations during the same phase (package phase) in javafx maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, plugins, javafx, pom.xml

I am using native bundle javafx maven plugin.
While building the native package , during the package phase , a .app and .dmg is created for my application .When the native bundle gets executed , both .app and .dmg are created at the same time .
After that my resource plugin copies a plugin from another project to the .app of this project.
But the problem is , the plugin gets copied to the .app but not the .dmg because .dmg is already created.
What my requirement is : I want some order to be mantained within the same package phase i.e. first I want my .app to be created , then I want the plugins to be copied and then I want the .dmg to be created .
Right now what is happening : .app is getting created then .dmg is getting created then plugin gets copied because of which the plugin is appearing in .app but not in .dmg

Answer (score 0):

Long technical reasons short: nope, not possible, because that plugin relies on the used `javapackager`-libs provided by oracle, which are constructed to re-create the `.app`-content when running `dmg`-bundler.

This is related to another SO-question: [Is it possible to placing Plugins(.appex) at a common location beforehand where JavaFX maven plugin would pick it and build the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539031/is-it-possible-to-placing-plugins-appex-at-a-common-location-beforehand-where)

This problem is going to be worked around and reported by thread-opener on: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/235

Just to inform other people searching and finding this SO-question ;)

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin and creator of the javafx-gradle-plugin.