# Is it possible to placing Plugins(.appex) at a common location beforehand where JavaFX maven plugin would pick it and build the app

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8, maven-plugin

I am working with JavaFX Maven Plugin to build my app on OS X.

During the build process , whatever lies in the app folder will be automatically placed in Java folder to the main app. Whatever lies in Info.plist and .icns will be picked up from deploy/package/macosx folder

But I have still not been able to figure out the position for placing the .appex file (Finder Extensions) in order to get them placed automatically inside the Plugins folder during the build process of the main application bundle.

I couldn't find much information available about this on JavaFX maven plugin document.

Please let me know if this has a workaround.

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin. You might want to get in contact with me, or put this [on the github-project](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) as an issue, maybe it is some bug, or just some configuration needed.

Comment: Hi , Thankyou for your reply. This is really high priority and I am going to raise an issue on github right away. I hope this can be resolved soon.